# Как защититься от wcrypt (Wanna Cry)?

Tags: безопасность, вирусы, wcrypt, wannacry

В свете текущих новостей решил задать вопрос по теме того, как обезопасить свой компьютер от популярного wcrypt (Wanna Cry/Wana Decrypt0r). У кого есть данные по этой теме?

Comment: https://geektimes.ru/post/289115/

Comment: скачайте с сайта мелкософта kb4012212 только свое 64 или 86 и установите, если у вас автоматически вставляться обновление то посмотрите обновление установлено или нет вышло оно в марте 2017 года.

Comment: А если оно у вас не установлено и не устанавливается - значит у вас не древняя семерка, которая вышла 8 лет назад, а что-то посвежее.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Обновление Windows MS17-010**

Вирус использует эксплоит ETERNALBLUE, которую закрывает выпущенное в марте обновление безопасности Microsoft MS17-010. Рекомендую проверить в центре обновления наличие такого обновления (по коду) на вашем компьютере (например, код для Windows 7 будет KB4012212 или KB4012215, **или любой другой ежемесячный набор исправлений качества системы безопасности начиная с мартовского (2017 год)**).

Если обновления не установлены, скачать их можно с официального сайта Microsoft:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx

Для старых систем (Windows XP, Windows Server 2003R2) Microsoft выпустил специальные патчи:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/2017/05/12/customer-guidance-for-wannacrypt-attacks/

**Закрываем порты 135 и 445**

По отчетам антивирусных компаний, wcrypt проникает на компьютеры через порты SMB (Server Message Block). Для предотвращения проникновения, блокируем порты 135 и 445, через которые проникает вирус (в большинстве случаев они не используются обычными пользователями).

Для этого открываем консоль с правами администратора (cmd.exe -> запуск от имени администратора). И выполняем в ней поочередно 2 команды (после каждой команды должен быть статус OK)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=block protocol=TCP localport=135 name="Block_TCP-135"

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=block protocol=TCP localport=445 name="Block_TCP-445"
```

**Отключение поддержки SMBv1**

Уязвимость также можно закрыть, полностью отключив поддержку SMBv1. Для этого достаточно выполнить следующую команду в командной строке запущенной от имени Администратора (для Windows 8 и выше):

```
dism /online /norestart /disable-feature /featurename:SMB1Protocol
```

**Обнаружение антивирусами**

Список антивирусов, которые по данным Virus Total от 17.05.2017 обнаруживают wcrypt:

https://virustotal.com/cs/file/b9c5d4339809e0ad9a00d4d3dd26fdf44a32819a54abf846bb9b560d81391c25/analysis/

Comment: Я ось ставил в апреле. Ни одно из обновлений не присутствует. Скачать kb4012215 и поставить руками нельзя - "обновление не применимо к данному компьютеру". Выключить SMB1Protocol нельзя - "Error: 0x800f080c                                                         
Имя компонента "SMB1Protocol" неизвестно
Имя компонента Windows не распознано."

Comment: @vitidev, значит вы используете не ОС Windows на своем компьютере :)

Comment: @vitidev kb4012215 - это апдейт для 7-ки.

Comment: @PashaPash У меня она и есть. В итоге поставилось 12212 и это при том, что обновление включено.

Comment: А касперский бы помог? Или антивирус был бы тут бесполезен?

Comment: @Khipster, антивирусы которые детектят этот вирус https://virustotal.com/cs/file/b9c5d4339809e0ad9a00d4d3dd26fdf44a32819a54abf846bb9b560d81391c25/analysis/ Базы у антивирусов должны быть свежими.

Comment: Тоже вчера задавался данным вопросом, вот что удалось найти: [Все, що вам слід знати про найбільшу вірусну атаку в історії Інтернету](http://www.bizmaster.xyz/2017/05/alll-you-need-to-know-about-WannaCry.html)

Answer (score 1):

Расскажу как я избавился от шифровальщиков в нашей корпоративной сети.

У нас в фирме около 1000 хостов и периодически компьютеры заражались шифровальщиками. И если корпоративную почту мы защитили, шифровальщики все равно устанавливались через личную почту или веб ресурсы.

Решение очень простое в групповых политиках "Конфигурация компьютера/конфигурация windows/Параметры безопасности/Политики ограниченного использования программ/Дополнительные правила" выставляем все пути через которые могут запускаться программы (programm files, Windows...). В назначенные типы файлов удаляем ярлыки и добавляем JS которых по дефолту почему то нет. И все. Эта политика была применена задолго до эпидемий Wanna Cry/Wana Decrypt0r и с тех пор ни одного заражения.

p.s. и конечно пользователи не должны сидеть под админом, ровно как и админы.